# Drupal hybridauth Paypal login issue

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-7, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

My website is loggin error while trying to login with Paypal in my Drupal 7 website by using hybridauth.

```
Exception: Authentication failed! Paypal returned an error: invalid_scope in Hybrid_Auth::initialize() (line 153 of /abc/xyz/public_html/mydomain/sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php).
```

I have created REST app in paypal and using the client id and secret. Could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

I have entered return url as https://www.mysite/hybridauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Paypal for test and live. And unchecked Accept payments because I do not need it.